# bit banging i2c trouble shooting

Tags: c, serial-port, avr, i2c, atmega

I am trying to implement bit-banging i2c to communicate between an atmega128A's GPIO and an SHT21 (I2C bus was used for some other devices). The first task is to send a write sequence to the SHT21. Using an oscilloscope, I can see that the sequence sending out from the atmega has the correct start signal, correct order of bits, correct stop signal, signal levels looks correct. The serial analyzer from the scope reads out correct I2C message: S80W~A . Yet there is not any ACK response from the SHT21. The SDA and SCL are both pulled up to 3.3V via 6.7K resistors.

I really need help finding out what is wrong

Thank you so much.

Comment: You may have better luck posting here - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have the GPIO pins set for "open-collector"? If you leave it normal, push-pull mode, the slave will be unable to pull down the SDA line to acknowledge the address. Try removing the pull-up resistors; if the waveform still looks good, you're in the wrong mode.

Comment: Also, is the slave device a true I2C/IIC device, or is it labelled as a TWI (Two Wire Interface) device? Some variants of I2C that are not "true" I2C require 3k resistor between the slave and the pull-up resistor for some odd reason (a lot of OmniVision Technologies chips require this for their I2C interfaces). Also, are you dead sure about the address you are pinging? If you set the slave address to 255 (0xFF), it broadcasts to all devices on the bus. Always worth trying that in case the slave address is re-programmable.

Comment: Hi @Dogbert, thank you for your comment, I am really sure about the address. I used the same modules on other MCUs with real I2C bus and they all worked fine with the address I am using. The slave device, SHT21, is a true I2C, SHT11, an older version is not.

Comment: This question appears to be cross-posted: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102957/bitbanging-i2c-problem-with-ack-from-slave